# ConverterParameter binding

Tags: wpf, binding

Подскажите, почему ConverterParameter вываливается с ошибкой "A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject"?

```
<TextBlock Tag="{Binding First}">
    <TextBlock.IsEnabled>
        <Binding Path="Second"
                 Converter="{StaticResource FirstAndSecondToBoolConverter}"
                 ConverterParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}"/>
    </TextBlock.IsEnabled>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: "Binding.ConverterParameter — не DependencyProperty, поэтому ему нельзя присвоить Binding"

Comment: Но если вам интересно, что с этим делать, то вам сюда https://habrahabr.ru/post/275223/